# How to get distance between points and multiple others

Tags: r, spatial, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to determine the distances (euclidean) between points I have in a data frame and others in another one. 
Here's below an example of data.

```
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

x1 <- rnorm(5)
y1 <- rnorm(5)
Id <- c(1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(Id, x1, y1)
```

I tried this formula to get distance:

```
sqrt(((df2$x1 - df$x)^2) + ((df2$y1 - df$y)^2))
```

But I cannot find how to get the distance between points by `Id` in the `df1` and all the others in `df`

thanks for the help

Comment: What is your desired outcome exactly? Did you want distances for each of the 5 `Id` with all of the `df` points? That would give 25 distances (or 5 distances for each `Id`)?

Comment: I want distances for each of the five ```Id``` in ```df2```. That would give me 25 distances right.

Comment: Yes it does !, Sorry I didn't see you were the personne who answered my question and comment the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get distances between each (x,y) point in `df2` with all of the other (x,y) points in `df`, you could do the following, using your Euclidean distance formula:

```
euclid_dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  sqrt(((x1 - x2)^2) + ((y1 - y2)^2))
}

t(apply(df2, 1, function(a) euclid_dist(a[["x1"]], a[["y1"]], df[["x"]], df[["y"]])))
```

With your data you would get in return:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

x1 <- rnorm(5)
y1 <- rnorm(5)
Id <- c(1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(Id, x1, y1)

         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.786003 1.9680289 3.070264 2.7295146 2.4865570
[2,] 1.525957 0.5911463 2.131949 1.2195161 0.9712662
[3,] 3.805099 2.5081895 1.353883 1.3216922 1.5449945
[4,] 1.215755 0.4171294 2.442043 1.3887899 1.1471688
[5,] 2.187861 0.9888714 2.258099 0.6619184 0.6856658
```

This matrix includes distances where each row represents each `Id` in `df2`.